# R remove rows with least entries in column

Tags: r

I have the below frame:

```
df <- read.table(text = "  id   name
1 100 Rank1
2 100 Rank1
3 100 Rank1
4 355 Rank1
5 300 Rank2
6 400 Rank2
7 400 Rank2",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

I want to keep only the rows that have the most same "id" in column ID. For example Rank 1, has 3x 100 id and 1x 355 and rank2 has 1x300 and 2x400. I want to only keep the 3x100 and 2x400 so it looks like:

```
   id  name
1 100 Rank1
2 100 Rank1
3 100 Rank1
4 400 Rank2
5 400 Rank2
```

How can i do that? This will be multiple a very large dataset with multiple ranks and multiple ids per rank.

Thanks

Comment: You could do `df[duplicated(df)|duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE),]` or with `dplyr`; `df %>% group_by(name, id) %>% filter(n() > 1)`

Comment: Suppose you have frequencies of 4, 3, 2, 1 fo each 'name', which one you would filter

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, if we wanted to remove the least frequent ones,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(name, id) %>% 
   mutate(n = n()) %>%
   group_by(name) %>% 
   filter(n != min(n)) %>% 
   select(-n)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   name [2]
#     id name 
#  <int> <chr>
#1   100 Rank1
#2   100 Rank1
#3   100 Rank1
#4   400 Rank2
#5   400 Rank2
```

---

Or using the same methodology with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, n := .N, .(name, id)][,  .I[n != min(n)], name]$V1
df[i1][, n := NULL][]
```

---

But, if we wanted to remove rows that have no duplicate 'id' for each 'name'

```
df[duplicated(df)|duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE),]
```

Comment: Thanks! This will tho be a large set with more than 100,000 entries and multiple IDs per Name. Will this still work?

Comment: @user3324658  It doesn't matter about the size as long as you have a good RAM,.  The logic should work

Comment: Hi unfortunatelly this does not work for what i need it for. It also removes several names. There are a lot of ids per name i dont know if that changes things. The above code also removes several unique names.

Comment: @user3324658  the code is based on the description.  Could you please update your post with a small example where this doesn't work along with the expected output